# Fetching data from api in componentDidMount is returning null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch data in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of react but I am not getting it.

**my method is:**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { taskId } = this.props
    getTask(taskId)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      this.setState({task: data});
    })
  }
```

**my api is:**

```
  export const getTask = (unique_id) =>  {
  console.log(unique_id)
    return fetch('https://punctual-backend-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/homeowner_tasks/'+ unique_id).then(res => { 
    return res.json();
    });
  };
```

**this is my whole component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { getTask } from '../../modules/clients';
import ClientTaskShow from '../../components/tasks/ClientTaskShow'

class ClientTaskShowContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      messageModalOpen: false,
      selectedPartnerId: null,
      task:{}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      console.log("hello")
    const { taskId } = this.props
    getTask(taskId)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      this.setState({task: data});
    })
  }
  render() {
    const taskSelected = this.state.task;
    console.log(taskSelected)
        return (
            <ClientTaskShow 
                task={taskSelected}
            />
        )   
  }
}

export default ClientTaskShowContainer;
```

**code from where calling clienttaskShowContainer:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import ClientTaskShowContainer from '../../containers/tasks/ClientTaskShowContainer'
import requireAuth from '../../lib/requireAuth'

const ClientTasksShow = ({ query }) => {
  const { taskId } = query
  return (
    <Layout fluid fullHeight clientTaskHeader='true'>
      <Head>
        <title>Client Task Details | Punctual</title>
      </Head>
      <ClientTaskShowContainer taskId={taskId} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

ClientTasksShow.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => ({
    query
  })

export default requireAuth(ClientTasksShow)
```

I think its not hitting the API even. Although it hit once I restart the server but not again. I am not able to replicate the problem. 
At some sites I found we should use `.then` for API call others says we can't pass perimeter in API call in componentDidMount. What is the exact solution for this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it really returning `null` ? If so, does the API even return JSON? Does the client actually hit the right API? Does `fetch` reject (attach a `.catch` to it!) ?

Comment: I guess even comonentDidMount is not working or called by

Comment: How do you know that? Does `"hello"` get logged?

Comment: no its not logged

Comment: can you provide a value for the unique_id which is been passed in the api as query params

Comment: If the lifecycle-method `componentDidMount` is not rendering your console.log() output, could you add the code where you implement <ClientTaskShowContainer />?

Comment: 7693fbf81a33 use this

Comment: Did you actually add the component to the page somewhere? Does the constructor get executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working

//Calling component

```
import React from "react";
import CallComp from "./CallComp";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CallComp taskId={"7693fbf81a33"} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ClientTaskShow from "./ClientTaskShow";

class ClientTaskShowContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      task: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { taskId } = this.props;
    fetch(
      `https://punctual-backend-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/homeowner_tasks/${taskId}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ task: data }))
      .catch(error => console.log("the error is", error));
  }
  render() {
    const taskSelected = this.state.task;
    console.log("task selected is ", taskSelected);
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(taskSelected).length ? (
          <ClientTaskShow task={taskSelected} />
        ) : (
          <div>No data to show</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClientTaskShowContainer;
```

// Demo ClientTaskShow

```
import React from "react";

const ClientTaskShow = ({ task }) => {
  return <h1>{task.unique_code}</h1>;
};

export default ClientTaskShow;
```

Comment: I have added demo ClientTaskShow for your reference, you could use any component that is accepting the task data from api. You need to change path for ClientTaskShow as well.

Comment: like you used an extra div same if I am using this is working but when using my component it is not

Comment: In react there should always be a single parent (root element), you could use <Fragment /> or just <></> to avoid <div> wrapping to solve this.

Comment: Thanks dude this was pretty helpful

Answer (score 1):

Actually its working

[image]

`console.log(data)` returns error message from api

Answer (score 0):

You should return promise from function to know api request is resolved or not

try this:

```
export const getTask = (id) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fetch('https://punctual-backend-staging.herokuapp.com/api/v1/homeowner_tasks/' + id).then((res) => {
            resolve(res.json())
        })
    });
}
```

And call like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    getTask(1).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });  
}
```

You can replace params with your id

Hope this helps.